# Formatting results of List in Python3 .4

Tags: python, list, string-formatting, python-3.4

I am trying to get the results of my list calculations to display in an orderly fashion by formatting the print() function.  I have tried various methods from this site and Python Docs.

The closest that I can get it to display in a table like format is to align the output using the .format() function, but a couple of the lines are still offset.  I understand that this is because the preceding results are longer than the others, but I can't figure out a way to get the text to align in columns.

When I try to amend the string formatting from what I already have I get a "tuple index out of range" error.  But as far as I am aware I'm not using Tuples?

This is the string I am trying to print:

```
print('{:<10}'.format("Richter Scale Value:"), '{:<10}'.format(rVal),'{:^10}'.format ("Joules:"),'{:^10}'.format(joules),'{:>10}'.format("TNT:"),'{:>10}'.format(tnt))
```

But the output I get is:

```
Richter Scale Value: 1           Joules:   1995262.3149688789       TNT: 0.00047687913837688307
Richter Scale Value: 5           Joules:   1995262314968.8828       TNT: 476.87913837688404
Richter Scale Value: 9.1         Joules:   2.818382931264449e+18       TNT: 673609687.2046962
Richter Scale Value: 9.2         Joules:   3.981071705534953e+18       TNT: 951498973.5982201
Richter Scale Value: 9.5         Joules:   1.1220184543019653e+19       TNT: 2681688466.3048882
```

I can't figure out how to get the last three 'TNT' lines to match up.

This is the code preceding the print():

```
rVal = 0
qList=[1,5,9.1,9.2,9.5]
qList_len = len(qList)
for i in range (0,qList_len):
    rVal = qList[i]
    joules = 10**((1.5*rVal)+4.8)
    tnt = joules/(4.184*10**9)
```

Any assistance will be gratefully received thanks.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, that's great. The extra understanding of the string formatting has helped immensely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly format your `joules` values a precision. You have only given a *minimum* width, but the default format exceeds that:

```
print('Richter Scale Value: {:<10.1f} Joules: {:<10.8g} TNT: {:10.8g}'.format(
    rVal, joules, tnt))
```

You may want to tweak the exact widths and how many decimals are displayed. You also could use `f` instead of `g` to always force displaying the values without scientific `e` notation, or use `e` to force scientific notation instead.

I combined your 6 `str.format()` calls into one. There is little point in formatting constant label strings.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to look for a maximum column width and format the table accordingly, a fixed value for width will obviously not work as the content length can vary in each cell.

A while ago I created a package for creating text tables called [txtable](https://github.com/atomgomba/txtable).